# How to display an Android Activity in Flutter?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am currently working on an app that uses Google Maps Api in flutter. Due to incomplete support I just get to use a static map, clicking upon which leads to an Android activity which is of no use. What I need is a map where I can search for a location and add a marker to that location. So is it possible to implement the Map View in native Java code and display it with Flutter widgets on top?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you think this plugin https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/map_view  doesn't fit your requirements, you can create your own native classes using `Platform Channels.`

Or maybe you can also fork the project and add new functionalities to contribute with the community :).

Refer to this documentation : https://flutter.io/platform-channels/