# Using Flutter, when running Google map in Android version less than 20, it does not work .. Is there any idea?

Tags: android, google-maps, flutter

I am a newbie in Flutter. I followed the following tutorial to create a Google map demo with Flutter ..

https://medium.com/flutter-io/google-maps-and-flutter-cfb330f9a245

I tried to run on my real device whose Android version is KitKat (Android 19) , but the map does not appear..

It shows me in the console the following:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on GT I9505 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Syncing files to device GT I9505...
E/PlatformViewsController(27523): Trying to use platform views with API 19, required API level is: 20
```

Although the Android Gradle is  ..

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    ...
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        ....
    }
```

When I run the demo on the emulator, It works well, but it does not work on my Andriod 19 device ..

Is there any idea to make the map works on the Android versions below 20? .. Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 3):

I got two solutions for this problem although I prefer one of them ..

1. First solution (which I prefer) .. is to create a Map Activity for android using Android Studio, and then displaying it by Flutter .. The same thing with iOS when building a map app for iOS and Android.

   You can refer to these links if you want to know how ..

   [How to display an Android Activity in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51824280/how-to-display-an-android-activity-in-flutter)

   https://medium.com/@Chetan/flutter-communicate-with-android-activity-or-ios-viewcontroller-through-method-channel-c11704429cd0

   https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels
2. The second solution (which I do not prefer) .. is by using [flutter_map](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map) package which is a Dart implementation of [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) for Flutter apps..

   It works, but very slow when navigating or zooming, and maybe it is freezing .. I don't know I am right in that or not .. But I noticed that when testing the program .. Anyway, please reply to me on the comments if there is any notes.

I still need to figure out why the [Google Maps Flutter plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) does not work in Android versions less than Lollipop (Android 21)!!!

Finally, if there is any notes about what I said, please tell me in the comments.

Comment: the first solution is not work anymore because the map_view lib is disconnected